# Does TestCafe end the node process once all tests are run? Reporter makes async calls and they never return

Tags: testing, automated-tests, slack-api, testcafe, gulp-mocha

I'm making a custom reporter that uploads files to Slack, shares them and returns the file link to the reporter (to add to the Slack message) but when I try this out in a real test run, the async calls to upload the file and share fire but it looks like the node process ends before they can return and be processed.
I'm quite sure this is happening as this isn't a problem in the `gulp test` run (that mocks a TestCafe test run) as the reporter sends off a Slack message with all the async data appended to it successfully.

Any ideas? I'm thinking of adding another fixture to my test to wait for a specified time so that the calls complete and the message is able to be sent.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. It was/is definitely the case with [testcafe-reporter-slack](https://github.com/Shafied/testcafe-reporter-slack) which is still listed in the official documentation for TestCafe.

Comment: @mostlyfabulous, please check that the async calls to upload and share files are awaited in your reporter. If this is not the cause of the issue, provide us wtih the reporter code. It should help to find the problem.